# Difference between java.policy and catalina.policy?

Tags: java, security, permissions

While accessing a file outside of tomcat from a webapp deployed in it, I got access denied issue. I was running tomcat with security manager enabled. After setting the permission on catalina.policy the issue got resolved. While I was checking about java security I came across java.policy and this too was about permissions to codebase and files. I've multiple instances of tomcat. To avoid editing permissions at multiple places, thought to enter in java.policy. But, when I grant the same permission in java.policy and remove in catalina.policy, the permission is not processed/granted and I see the issue occurring. So, I want to understand their differences and how to address this from java.policy

Comment: Guys...any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to put this in simple terms. java.policy and catalina.policy intend to provide security access to users applications/programs.

**Difference:**

*java.policy*:
Usually this file is present in respective jre the application is accessing. So, for all JVMs in the system this policy is used. Even a custom policy can be used.

*catalina.policy*:
This file is present in tomcat and enabled with security manager in tomcat. The purpose of this file too is same as java.policy, but this addresses to respective instances of tomcat. This file overrides java.policy as this has few explicit permissions for tomcat itself which are needed when security manager is enabled in tomcat.